# How do I write a test for a controller?

Tags: unit-test, controller

Just curious how I write a unit test for a controller for a VF page? Here is the controller. Please see my comment for more detail. Not looking for someone to do it - just wondering the "how"... my brain was just not grasping it.

```
public class AccountSearchController {

  // the soql without the order and limit
  private String soql {get;set;}
  // the collection of accounts to display
  public List<Account> accounts {get;set;}

  // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
  public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }

  // the current field to sort by. defaults to account name 
  public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Name'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
  }

  // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
  public String debugSoql {
    get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' Limit 200'; }
    set;
  }

  // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
  public AccountSearchController() {
    soql = 'select Name, Type,Account_Management_Type__c, Territory_Vertical__c, Tier__c, Subsidiary__c,Overall_Status__c, Industry, Territory__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c != null';
    runQuery();
  }

  // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
  public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
  }

  // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {

    try {
      accounts = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' Limit 200');
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
    }

  }

  // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
  public PageReference runSearch() {

    String Name = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name');
    String accManage = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accManage');
    String overall = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('overall');
    String Industry = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Industry');
    String Vertical = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Vertical');      
    String Tier = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Tier');      
    String Sub = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Sub');      
    String Territory = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Territory');
    String Types = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Types'); 


    soql = 'select Name, Account_Management_Type__c, Type, Overall_Status__c,  Territory_Vertical__c, Tier__c, Subsidiary__c, Industry, Territory__c from Account where Account_Management_Type__c != null';
    if (!Name.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Name LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(Name)+'%\'';
    if (!accManage.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Account_Management_Type__c LIKE \''+accManage+'\'';
    if (!Industry.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Industry LIKE \''+Industry+'\'';
    if (!Vertical.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Territory_Vertical__c LIKE \''+Vertical+'\'';
    if (!Tier.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Tier__c LIKE \''+Tier+'\'';
    if (!Sub.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Subsidiary__c LIKE \''+Sub+'\'';  
    if (!Types.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Type LIKE \''+Types+'\'';      
    if (!Territory.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Territory__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(Territory)+'%\'';

    // run the query again
    runQuery();

    return null;
  }

      // use apex describe to build the type picklist values
  public List<String> Types {
    get {
      if (Types == null) {

        Types = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Type.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          Types.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return Types;          
    }
    set;
  }
  // use apex describe to build the industry picklist values
  public List<String> Industry {
    get {
      if (Industry == null) {

        Industry = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Industry.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          Industry.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return Industry;          
    }
    set;
  }
  // use apex describe to build the vertical picklist values
  public List<String> Vertical {
    get {
      if (Vertical == null) {

        Vertical = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Territory_Vertical__c.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          Vertical.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return Vertical;          
    }
    set;
  }
    // use apex describe to build the tier picklist values
  public List<String> Tier {
    get {
      if (Tier == null) {

        Tier = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Tier__c.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          Tier.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return Tier;          
    }
    set;
  }
     // use apex describe to build the subsidiary picklist values
  public List<String> Sub {
    get {
      if (Sub == null) {

        Sub = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Subsidiary__c.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          Sub.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return Sub;          
    }
    set;
  }

      // use apex describe to build the Account Management picklist values
  public List<String> Accmanage {
    get {
      if (accmanage == null) {

        accmanage = new List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = Account.Account_Management_Type__c.getDescribe();

        for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues())
          accmanage.add(f.getLabel());

      }
      return accmanage;          
    }
    set;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Merry, you are not likely to get many good answers on this question since you are basically asking us to do your work. I will still try to write something up for you that will get you started.

Comment: Although p11y provided a very nice answer.  I agree that this question should be edited or closed as you are just asking for the community to write your test code.

Comment: I was not asking for anyone to do it for me, and I should have given more information in my question - I will edit it. What I was wondering is how you write it for a controller, I understand how to do it for a trigger, as a trigger is performing an action. I was just not sure how to do this for a controller - I could not wrap my brain around it. I appreciate the feedback and answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Unit Testing

The idea of a great unit test is to make sure that your code actually does what it is supposed to do. So writing tests is all about trying hard to break your own code and then fixing those errors. Put differently, you cannot learn anything from a test that is passing, only from one that is failing. If you then go ahead and fix the problem, you have actually improved your code. If you have maybe heard of Test Driven Development or TDD before, this is the idea behind it. Write a test that fails before you implement your functionality, then write the actual implementation, then verify that the test is passing, and so on.

Now to controller tests in general. There are typically two different types of tests that you will write. One type is for actual controller actions, the other (simpler) type occurs with public fields and auxiliary methods. I will try to give you an example for each type.

### Tests for controller actions

Here, you are basically testing on the highest level of abstraction and complexity. This happens because most of the time, you are just calling one method from VisualForce, while lots of things happen in the background. In your case, this would basically be tests for `runSearch()`. Tests for controller actions generally have this basic structure:

```
@isTest
static void testRunSearchByName() {
    // setup database objects like accounts etc.
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{
        Account(Name = 'Acc 1'),
        Account(Name = 'Acc 2'),
        Account(Name = 'Acc 3')
    };
    insert accounts;

    // setup page and controller
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.AccountSearch);
    AccountSearchController con = new AccountSearchController();

    // setup other stuff like get parameters etc.
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Name', 'Acc 2');
    // ...

    // Marks the beginning and end of the code that you actually
    // test here. This is a good habit, because it resets limits
    // that you have already wasted during setup and which would
    // not occur if the controller action would be run by a user
    Test.startTest();

    // code to test, i.e. call to controller action

    Test.stopTest();

    // assertions - check that everything behaves as expected
}
```

Now a more concrete example for your `runSearch()` method:

```
@isTest
static void testRunSearchByName() {
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>{
        Account(Name = 'Acc 1'),
        Account(Name = 'Acc 2'),
        Account(Name = 'Acc 3')
    };
    insert accounts;

    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.AccountSearch);
    AccountSearchController con = new AccountSearchController();
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Name', 'Acc 2');

    Test.startTest();
    con.runSearch();
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assertNotEquals(null, con.accounts);
    System.assertEquals(1, con.accounts.size());
    System.assertEquals(accounts.get(1), con.accounts.get(0));
}
```

Now this is only a test for searching by name and only if the name actually exists. From this test alone, we know nothing about how this thing behaves when  a) adding no name parameter, b) submitting a name that does not exist, c) trying  to search for another field. You will have to write tests for all that, but i'll leave that as an exercise for you. You might of course add more assertions to your tests, the assertions above are just an example. You should test the contents of everything that you want to access from the VF page after the controller action ran.

It is very common, that the number of lines in a test class is about two to four times larger that the number of lines in the class that you are actually testing. But if you decide to change your code later on you will be happy that you have the tests since they will show you every little detail that you just broke.

### Tests for public fields and methods

Some methods do not need to be tested with multiple inputs, because they will always return the same values. These can be public fields (e.g. in your case picklist values) or just auxiliary methods (e.g. in your case `toggleSort()`). You should always consider making those `static` if possible. This makes them much easier to test, because you don't need all that complicated setup we've seen above. You just test the method and you're done.

Here's how I would write a test for one of your picklist values fields:

```
@isTest
public static void testTypesPicklistValues() {
    AccountSearchController con = new AccountSearchController();
    Set<String> values = new Set<String>(con.Types);

    System.assert(values.contains('Picklist Value One'));
    System.assert(values.contains('Picklist Value Two'));
    // ...
}
```

I am using a `Set` here because that gives me access to the `contains` method which I find very handy. As you see, this type of test generally is a lot simpler to follow and has less clutter. Again, i'll leave the rest of the tests as an exercise for you ;-)

## Possible improvements in your code

Apart from that here are some suggestions how you might improve your code:

### Checking for blank strings

**Use `if(String.isBlank(someString))` instead of `if(!someString.equals(''))`**. The problem with this is that it will raise an exception when given a `null` value, which is exactly what salesforce gives you when you select an empty field from the database, or in your case, try to access a URL parameter that might not be present. `String.isBlank` however will behave as expected and just assume that `null` should also be treated as a blank string, without ugly errors.

### Code duplication

**Try to refactor more**. For example, the first lines of your `runSearch()` method are very repetitive. You could write them this way:

```
Map<String, String> params = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters();
String Name      = params.get('Name');
String accManage = params.get('accManage');
// etc.
```

Same thing applies to your picklist values fields. They are all almost the same code. You can refactor out a method, say `buildPicklistValues` that takes a describe result and builds picklist values the same way for all fields:

```
private static List<String> buildPicklistValues(Schema.DescribeResult field) {
    List<String> picklistValues = new List<String>();

    for (Schema.PicklistEntry f : field.getPicklistValues()) {
        picklistValues.add(f.getLabel());
    }

    return picklistValues;
}
```

then for all your picklists do

```
public List<String> Types {
    get {
        if (Types == null) {
            Types = buildPicklistValues(Account.Type.getDescribe());
        }
        return Types;
    }
    set;
}

// etc.
```

This kind of thing will also help you test your code better, because you will end up with smaller methods that are easier to test.

Comment: may be you can write community wiki for test in general.